# Problem with setState in React Native/ Expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, expo, expo-av

I'm learning React Native with Expo and I encountered this problem where `setState` doesn't update the state when i pass a value. I'm trying to make a function that play audio and save its control to a state whenever i press on a button:

```js
import React, { useState} from "react";
import { Audio } from "expo-av";
```

```js
const [soundObj, setSoundObj] = useState(null);
const [soundStatus, SetSoundStatus] = useState(null);
```

```js
const handleAudioPress = async (audio) => {
        try {
            console.log(soundStatus); // always null (initial value)
            if (!soundStatus) {
                const sound = new Audio.Sound();
                const sanitizedUri = audio.uri
                    .replace(/#/g, "%23")
                    .replace(/\?/g, "%3F")
                    .replace(/ /g, "%20");
                const stt = await sound.loadAsync(
                    { uri: sanitizedUri },
                    { shouldPlay: true }
                );

                console.log(sound) //always show the right value
                console.log(stt) //always show the right value

                setSoundObj(sound); //doesn't work???
                SetSoundStatus(stt); //doesn't work???
            }
            if (soundStatus && soundStatus.isLoaded && soundStatus.isPlaying) {
                console.log('sound is playing');
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    };
```

I passed this function through props:

```js
const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
        return (
            <AudioListItem
                title={item.filename}
                duration={item.duration}
                onAudioPress={() => handleAudioPress(item)}
                onOptionPress={() => {
                    currentItem.current = item;
                    setModalVisibility((v) => !v);
                }}
            />
        );
    };
```

Here is where it is used:

```js
export default function AudioListItem({ title, duration, onOptionPress,onAudioPress }) {
    return (
        <>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={onAudioPress}>
                    <View style={styles.left}>
                        //...irrevelant code
```

I put `console.log` right above the `setState` and it always showed the right value. I've tried making a deep copy of the values that i need and pass to the `setState` - doesn't work; pass an interger - still doesn't work. I had basic knowledge about React but i don't know if there are differents in `useState` of React and React Native, please give me some insight about the problem.

Comment: I don't see any issue with the way you have enqueued the state updates. What exactly makes you think the state updates are not working?

Comment: @DrewReese as the 1st `console.log` always show `null`, i don't think the state got updated from the `setState`.

Comment: You mean the first console log where you log the unupdated/initial state? Why would that indicate any issue with the state update?

Comment: @DrewReese i mean running the function multiple times always show the same result. I understand that the first run will show `null`, which is right. But if the `setState` successfully update the state then from the 2nd run onward the first `console.log` should have showed the update state? or maybe i'm missing something here?

Comment: Where or how is this `handleAudioPress` being used? Is it being memoized and thus not ever receiving an updated closure? Can you [edit] to include a complete [mcve]?

Comment: @DrewReese This function runs when i press a button. I pass this function through props to use in a child component, which is `<TouchableWithoutFeedback/>`, on `onPress` event.

Comment: Where is `renderItem` called? Please just [edit] to include a full and complete [mcve] of all the relevant component code so we don't have to play 20 questions to get the whole thing.

Comment: @DrewReese thank you for the help, i think it's better that i should go do more research before asking. Since the question got closed i think we can end the post here.

Answer (score 0):

useState is working, but the problem is, it's not update the value in real time
if you try to access the state after updating, it will not work, you need to use useEffect to watch the value and decide the flow.

this will not work..

```
                console.log(sound) //always show the right value
                console.log(stt) //always show the right value

                setSoundObj(sound); //doesn't work???
                SetSoundStatus(stt); //doesn't work???
            }

            if (soundStatus && soundStatus.isLoaded && soundStatus.isPlaying) {
                console.log('sound is playing');
            }
```

this will work..

```
const handleAudioPress = async (audio) => {
        try {
            console.log(soundStatus); // always null (initial value)
            if (!soundStatus) {
                const sound = new Audio.Sound();
                const sanitizedUri = audio.uri
                    .replace(/#/g, "%23")
                    .replace(/\?/g, "%3F")
                    .replace(/ /g, "%20");
                const stt = await sound.loadAsync(
                    { uri: sanitizedUri },
                    { shouldPlay: true }
                );

                console.log(sound) //always show the right value
                console.log(stt) //always show the right value

                setSoundObj(sound); //doesn't work???
                SetSoundStatus(stt); //doesn't work???
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    };

useEffect(() => {
            if (soundStatus && soundStatus.isLoaded && soundStatus.isPlaying) {
                console.log('sound is playing');
            }
}, [soundStatus])
```